# Game Center authentication Handler will not dismiss Game Center login modal view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, game-center, modalviewcontroller

Got Game Center authentication working but when the Game Center 'Welcome' view controller appears in the view it will not dismiss. Hit cancel, the cancel action is sent but the view controller remains in the view. Complete user sign in, user is successfully signed in but the view controller remains, create a new appleID and at the end when complete the view controller remains.

Why is the Game Center view controller not dismissing?

```
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){

        if (viewController != nil) {

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

        } else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated) {

             NSLog(@"Game Center Authenticated");
             [self loginUser:blockLocalPlayer];

        } else {

             NSLog(@"Game Center Disabled");
             [self loginUser:nil];
        }

        if (error) NSLog(@"Error authenticating Game Center: %@", error);
     };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

Instead of:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

should have used:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```